# HTML5 scrolling issue

Tags: html, css, cordova

I am developing a mobile application in Phonegap. Everything is working perfectly with a small CSS3 issue. The issue that I am facing is, while scrolling up/down it is scrolling but its not very smooth.
After few days of observation I noticed that I can scroll after second click/drag.
When I scroll/move screen first time on phone, nothing or very little movement is observed. But when I scroll second time, its scrolls very smoothly.

Mostly I feel, its because my phone is expecting second tab/click/touch or something. How do I tell my phone not to wait for double tab while scroll and start scrolling view?

regards

Comment: CAn you shouw us your code??

Comment: show your code.unless we cant able to know what yours problem